# Angualar - change object into array with specific structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

Good morning,
could someone help me with changing Object like this

```
    {
    item1: "this is string field value",
    item2: "FF FF A2 C4h"
    }
```

And i need to get this format of array

```
[
 {
  id: item1, value: "this is string field value"
 },
 {
  id: item2, value: "FF FF A2 C4"
 }
]
```

I know how I could solve this, for example, using it
Object.keys() or Object.values().

But I always get only one parameter out of two. And then the combination of these two results I am not able to put together. Therefore, I want to ask if anyone knows about a better / simpler solution. Or if someone could show me what I'm doing wrong and what is solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need {id: item1} or {id: "item1"} (string value) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get hold of both key and value at same time.

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs

Try something as below:

```js
const someArray = Object.entries(someObject).map(([key, value]) => ({id: key, value: value}))
```

Comment: Amazing thats what i need. I completely forgot about Object.entries () and how to use it in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `Object.keys()`, you can work as below:

```js
let input = {
    item1: "this is string field value",
    item2: "FF FF A2 C4h"
};

let result: {id: string, value: string}[] = [];

Object.keys(input).forEach(function(k) {
    let key = k as keyof typeof input;
    result.push({
        id: k,
        value: input[key]
    });
});
```

[Sample Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAlgdgDgV0gXggbwFAW9MIC2AjAFwQBEYAFlAM7R01gBOsA5hAGZQjAAmEANwCGwBCDIAaLDih58AJlJkAYsoiqIAQXkQAwgBZKZDAF8A3BgyhITEDQTAwpNFF6lGLGKwmCRY98xsJgDaALoQqGEWGADyAEYAViAAxmAAdADWIACeNAAUsIhgAJRpHAD2TACiQsmUeRwIMKlQ5TB5GcXo0tjWEFnZEf0QQnQD5RwQYNlwIBPQ8EgWOBC29o5piDT1mCsrrqQZUns4wqIgpIVIwQOhPRAmxRaP0cltNOWgacDlrHlrDhKZiAA)